# C# checkboxlist: How to avoid changing the checkbox state by clicking on the label?

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

how do I avoid that an item in a C#-checkboxlist can be selected by clicking on the label? So, the state of the checkbox should only be changed by clicking onto the box, but not by clicking on the label.

Can anyone please give me a hint?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is it a good idea to break with convention for those users who are used to being able to select checkboxes via their labels? I usually file bugs against applications which have somehow broken this.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that's a good point, thanks. So, a solution might also be a change of the checkboxes state if the label is clicked by the user. However, at the moment the onClick-action is triggered either by a click on the checkbox (=> the checkbox state changes) or by a click on the label (=> the checkbox state persists). A action triggered by a click on the lable without a changed checkbox state might confuse the user. So I'd like to either disable this effect or get also a changed checkbox state by clicking the label. Hopefully you got the idea behind my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a checkbox without text and add a seperate label next to the checkbox

Comment: Hi @Tecto, that's right. I tried this at first, but the checkboxes should act as a 'checkboxgroup' and the logic to implement this is much more complicated if you have to build the checkbox group / list from scratch. So I decided to use a checkboxlist.